# Retrieve webpage including AJAX content

Tags: json, vba, excel, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I've been using VBA to retrieve stock prices from the ASX website (www.asx.com.au) for quite some time, however, my script no longer works as the website has been updated and now uses javascripts to build the content.

As a result, the script shown below now return the  sections rather than the page content.

The VBA (pretty stock standard):

```vb
With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", strURL, False
    .send
    http.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
```

And the .responseText contains things like:

```html
<SCRIPT>
    var urlArray = window.location.hash.split('/');
    if (urlArray != null) {
      var var1 = urlArray[1];
      window.location = "http://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/companyInfo.do?by=asxCode&asxCode=" + var1;
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

How can I retrieve the webpage as one would view it in the browser?  The only thing I've not tried is creating a browser object can grabbing the HTML from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The website http://www.asx.com.au has an API available. I opened a page in Chrome for one of the companies - AMC by the link http://www.asx.com.au/asx/share-price-research/company/AMC, then opened Developer Tools window (<kbd>F12</kbd>), Network tab, and examined XHRs in the list after the page was loaded after I clicked each section. I found several URLs which return data in JSON format:

- https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/company/AMC?fields=primary_share,latest_annual_reports,last_dividend,primary_share.indices
- https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/company/AMC/similar?compare=marketcap
- https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/company/AMC/announcements?count=10&market_sensitive=false
- https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/chart/highcharts?asx_code=AMC&years=10
- https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/share/AMC/prices?interval=daily&count=10
- https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/company/AMC/dividends/history?years=5
- https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/company/AMC/dividends
- https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/company/AMC/options?count=5000
- https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/company/AMC/warrants?count=5000
- https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/company/AMC/people

To see a structure of the presented data the response contents could be copied and pasted to any JSON viewer (e. g. this online tool http://jsonviewer.stack.hu).

You may use the below VBA code to parse response from the URL https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/share/AMC/prices and output result. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test_query_ASX()

    Const Transposed = False ' Output option

    Dim sCode As String
    Dim sInterval As String
    Dim sCount As String
    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aRows()
    Dim aHeader()

    sCode = "AMC"
    sInterval = "daily"
    sCount = "10"

    ' Get JSON via API
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/share/" & sCode & "/prices?interval=" & sInterval & "&count=" & sCount, False
        .Send
        sJSONString = .ResponseText
    End With
    ' Parse JSON response
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid JSON"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Pick core data
    vJSON = vJSON("data")
    ' Convert each data set to array
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aRows, aHeader
    ' Output array to worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        If Transposed Then
            Output2DArray .Cells(1, 1), WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aHeader)
            Output2DArray .Cells(1, 2), WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aRows)
        Else
            OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
            Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aRows
        End If
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Run `Sub Test_query_ASX()` to process data. The output on the Sheet1 for me is as follows:

[image: output]

Having that example you can extract the data you need from the JSON responses by the listed URLs. BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).

**UPDATE**

After some changes on the web site it is necessary to use `https://www.asx.com.au/asx/...` instead of `http://www.asx.com.au/b2c-api/...`, so I fixed all of the above URLs.

Comment: Thanks @omegastripes!  I'll give this a go today and get back to you.
 (Shuffling between the computer and shed, building a doll cot for my daughter). Cheers!

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm, @omegastripes.  As I only need the last closing price returning the value from the JSON text could be done with string functions easily enough.

Of greatest value was your insight into determining how the HTML was generated through the various scripts and API, and will be of considerable value for future applications.  For this I am extremely grateful!  Thanks a million.

Comment: Having done a bit more digging, I have discovered that the http://www.asx.com.au/b2c-api/1/share/AMC/prices returns the price history, being the previous day or older.

To recover live data at the standard delayed price info (20 minutes), please use http://www.asx.com.au/b2c-api/1/share/AMC/?fields=primary_share

Comment: @omegastripes I tried to examine the XHR but has this since changed? The api still works but maybe their pages are hiding this info now?

Comment: Nevermind found them under network instead of XHR for some reason

Comment: @omegastripes  Are there any rate limit on these api?

Comment: @DotnetShadow, not as far as I know.  My sheet uses the call as a function, and would make at least 30 or 40 requests upon recalculation (depending on how many companies I'm following at any one time). Yet to run into trouble.